# Breaking a form down into smaller FormTypes

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form for, example, Person. A Person entity has various attributes such as firstname,surname,eyecolor,haircolor etc etc etc. All good. I create a PersonFormType and the form is constructed with calls to add():-

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstName', TextFilterType::class, [
                'condition_pattern'=>FilterOperands::OPERAND_SELECTOR,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => "person.firstName",
                'error_bubbling' => false,
            ]
        )
        ->add('surname', TextFilterType::class, [
            'condition_pattern'=>FilterOperands::OPERAND_SELECTOR,
            'required' => false,
            "label" => "person.surname",
        ])
```

Now suppose I want to break out firstname and surname to a NameFilterType thus:-

```
class NameFilterType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', TextFilterType::class, [
                    'condition_pattern'=>FilterOperands::OPERAND_SELECTOR,
                    'label' => "person.firstName",
                    'error_bubbling' => false,
                ]
            )
            ->add('surname', TextFilterType::class, [
                'condition_pattern'=>FilterOperands::OPERAND_SELECTOR,
                'required' => false,
                "label" => "person.surname",
            ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'name_filter';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'required' => false,
            'data_class' => "AppBundle\Entity\Person",
            'translation_domain' => null,
        ]);
    }

}
```

Now the question is how so I add that to my original form? Im guessing im missing something obvious. But if I try something like:

```
$builder
            ->add('name', NameFilterType::class, []);
```

At run time it doesnt work because the get parameter is

> person_filter.name.firstname

for example. How do I tell symfony's form mechanism to ignore the "logical name" of 'name' for this embedded form fragment?

Comment: Basically you would need to create a PersonName entity/value object and then modify your PersonEntity to use PersonName in place of firstname/surname.  Really up to you if it is worthwhile going through this just to break up a form type.  Might also be possible to just add a Person::getName() method which just returns an array.  And a corresponding setName.

Comment: you can work with PersonFormType, in twig display just name, surname form fields and use render_rest = false. define and use different validation_groups